# Create a responsive <figcaption>

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I have a website that when users hover on an image, the figcaption will slide up.

My screen resolution is 1024 x 768, and the image resolution is 300 x 400 pixels. It works perfectly for my screen resolution. Recently I realized how important a responsive website is, so I am trying to transform my whole website into a responsive one. But then my figcaption will not work for resolution like 1366 x 768. Below are the code I use and the images that try to explain the problem I encounter.

Each figure I use is 300x400. I used width:30% in #hello figure because there are 3 pictures, so I give each of them a width:30%.

Code in image.php:

```
<div id="hello">
   <figure>
      <img src="hello.png" alt="hello"/>
           <figcaption>
              <p>Hello </p>
              <br/>
              <p>Hello everyone!</p>
           </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

my css:

```
#hello{ 
   width:100%;
}

#hello figure{

    width: 30%;
    height: 400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Fredericka the Great', cursive;   
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    padding:0;
    margin: 15px;
}

#hello figcaption{
    position: relative;
    top: -105px;
    background: rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: top 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: top 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: top 1s ease;
    -o-transition: top 1s ease;
}

#hello figure:hover figcaption{
        top:-210px;
    }
```

When it is in 1024 x 768 resolution, it has no problem:

(not hover yet in 1024 x 768 resolution)

[image]

hover in 1024 x 768 resolution

[image]

When it is in 1366 x 768 resolution, it has problem of the figcaption overflowing.

[image]

[image]

Please share your valuable knowledge and advice with me. Thank you so much.

**EDIT:** If I set the figcaption width to 300px ( adding the line width:300px to #hello figcaption), it would look like this:

[image]

Comment: why not make the caption as wide as the image or figure element?

Comment: I tried to set the width of the figcaption to 300px, but that didn't work. I added another picture which I set the width of figcaption to 300px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set width to `figcaption` or `figure` it works:

```
img {
  width:300px;
}
figure {
  outline:solid;
    width:300px;

}
figcaption {
  outline:solid;

}
```

**Demo**: http://jsbin.com/ogoxop/1/edit

For real responsive layout you may also want to use media queries, to adjust widths based on device.

Comment: Yea seems like I gotta use media queries. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/weCLp/

where you've set the wrapper to `position: relative;` , and the captions to `position: absolute; bottom: 0; width:100%` to keep them on the bottom, and fitting in the container

```
#hello{ 
   width:100%;
}

#hello figure{
    width: 25%;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Fredericka the Great', cursive;   
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    padding:0;
    margin: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

#hello figcaption{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}

#hello figure:hover figcaption{
        height: 6em;
    }

img { 
     width: 100%; 
}
```

( edit: missed that you want the entire image visible at all times )